# How do I select all Child Components from my Parent Component and then uncheck a few while retaining the other checked components?

Tags: reactjs

I have a checkbox in my parent component which when checked selects all child components.

In my child component, I have checkboxes whose checked property is controlled (checked={this.state.checked || this.props.checkAll}). Now I am able to select all child elements at once. But when I try to uncheck only a single component I cant since the this.props.checkAll is true.

How Do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical example of parent child checkbox. A easy way is you can use this library. https://github.com/Robert-W/react-checkbox-tree. If you want to implement on your own one best way is to rather than storing the state as check all you need to store which one is checked and which one is unchecked. And when you click a parent and if it has a child then check all the child and store it in parent's state. If you uncheck use a callback to change the state of the parent by mentioning that it is unchecked. So every parent will have information about which child is checked. And child can access and change through callback

Answer (score 0):

Always set the state, if the data is changing and not directly use props to validate internally.

A component state management helps to control the internal data manipulation. So you should be doing the same in say constructor or `componentWillReceiveProps` and another `handleEvent`:

```
class Parent extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { allChecked: false ,
            childItems = [ { text: 'one', selected: false }, 
                { text: 'two', selected: false }, 
                { text: 'three', selected: false }
            ]
        };
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
        if (!this.props.checkAll && newProps.checkAll) {
            this.setState({ allChecked: newProps.checkAll });
        }
    }

    handleCheckChange(itemSelected, selected) {
        allChecked = false;
        let index = this.state.childItems.findIndex( (item) => item.text === itemSelected.text );
        let newitem = Object.assign({}, this.state.childItems[index]);
        newitem.selected = selected;

        if (selected === true){
            if (this.state.childItems.findIndex((item) => item.selected === false) === -1) {
                allChecked = true;
            }
            this.setState
        }

        this.setState({ allChecked: false,
            childItems: [
                ...this.state.childItems.slice(0, index),
                newItem,
                ...this.state.childItems.slice(index+1)
            ]
        });
    }

    render() {
        return {
            <div>
                <div>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="parent" value={this.state.allChecked} /> Parent
                </div>
                <div>
                    <ChildComponent items={this.state.childItems} onCheckChange={ (itemSelected) => handleCheckChange(itemSelected) } />
                </div>
            </div>
        };
    }
}
```

On similar note, you need state management to decide the checked state.

P.S.: Not test code.